# Sending emails with a PDF attachment (C#)

Tags: c#

I have an intranet site to manage clients' communications. There are only a few controls: a textbox for the Subject, Attachment (fileUpload control), and a multiline textbox for the content of the email.

Using the fileUpload control, I select the pdf file that I want to send to clients. All the details about the clients (name, email address, etc) is coming from a sql table.

The sending works just fine, it sends the email with the attachment. However, the PDF attachment cannot be opened. The error is that the file hasn't been correctly decoded. I am not sure where the problem is. Does anyone have an idea on where the problem is?

Here is the code (for the sending procedure):

```
protected void BtnSendAcctClientsEmail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uplAcctngAttachment.HasFile)
        {
            HttpPostedFile uploadedFile = uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile;
            if (IsAcctngFileHeaderValid(uploadedFile))
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
                string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
                if (strExtension != ".pdf")
                {
                    lblAcctngFileErr.Text = "Please attach pdf files only.";
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblAcctngFileErr.Text = "";
                }

                try
                {
                    DataSet ds_Emails = new DataSet();

                    constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS"].ConnectionString;
                    cn = new SqlConnection(constr);

                    cmd = new SqlCommand("getAcctClientsEmailAddresses", cn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    SqlDataAdapter da_Emails = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    cn.Open();
                    da_Emails.Fill(ds_Emails);
                    cn.Close();

                    for (int vLoop = 0; vLoop < ds_Emails.Tables[0].Rows.Count; vLoop++)
                    {
                        string name_first = ds_Emails.Tables[0].Rows[vLoop]["contact_fname"].ToString();
                        email = ds_Emails.Tables[0].Rows[vLoop]["email"].ToString();
                        client_id = ds_Emails.Tables[0].Rows[vLoop]["id"].ToString();
                        clientType = "acctng";

                        // Build the Body of the message using name_first into a string and then send mail.

                        //send e-mail
                        string fromAddress = "associates@example.com";
                        string ccAddress = fromAddress;

                        string subject = txtAcctngSubject.Text;
                        string sendEmail = "Dear " + name_first + "," + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + txtAcctngMessage.Text;
                        sendEmail += Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Go to https://www.example.com/crm_removal.aspx?id=" + client_id +
                        "&type=" + clientType + " to be removed from any future communications.";

                        MailAddress fromAdd = new MailAddress(fromAddress, "Associates");
                        MailAddress toAdd = new MailAddress(email);
                        MailMessage eMailmsg = new MailMessage(fromAdd, toAdd);
                        Attachment attachment;
                        attachment = new Attachment(uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName);

                        eMailmsg.Subject = subject;
                        eMailmsg.Attachments.Add(attachment);
                        eMailmsg.Body = sendEmail;

                        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                        client.Send(eMailmsg);
                    }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</script>");
                    sendingErr = ex.Message;
                    SendErr();
                }
                Response.Redirect("default.aspx", false);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsAcctngFileHeaderValid(HttpPostedFile uploadedFile)
    {
        Stream s = uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream;
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        int value;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            value = s.ReadByte();
            if (value == -1)
            {
                throw new Exception("Invalid file data.");
            }

            buffer.Append(value.ToString());
        }

        /*extension code list for files  
     
         * 7780 = exe
         * 8075 = docx
         * 3780 = pdf
         * 7173 = gif   
         * 255216 = jpg  
         * 13780 = png  
         * 6677 = bmp  
         * 208207 =xls, doc, ppt  
         * 8075 = xlsx,zip,pptx,mmap,zip  
         * 8297 = rar     
         * 01 = accdb,mdb  
         */

        string[] input = { "208207", "8075", "3780", "255216", "13780", "6677" };
        List<string> headers = new List<string>(input);
        return headers.Contains(buffer.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: When you pass the stream to the `Attachment` ctor it's offset by the 2 bytes you read earlier in `IsAcctngFileHeaderValid()` corrupting the data.  If you can't rewind the stream create a copy to use when you examine it for its header.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. When I go through the code, the bytes read is 3780, for the pfd signature.

Comment: try passing content type, new Attachment(uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName,"application/pdf");

Comment: Thank you for your input, Nonik. I still get "Acrobat Could not open 'filename' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Comment: In `IsAcctngFileHeaderValid` You call `s.ReadByte()` twice which moves the position of the stream to the 3rd byte, when you then pass the *same stream* to `new Attachment(...)` the `Attachment` object will read the stream from the *current* position (3) which means the data is missing the 1st 2 bytes and is corrupt.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something...it does two passes and gets the 2 bytes...the first pass sets 37 to int value, the second pass sets 80 to int value, and sets the buffer to 3780.

Comment: Yep but the stream has a "bookmark" to remember where it is every time you read from it, you have moved that book mark 2 places because of your 2 reads (37 & 80).  When you later give the same stream to `Attachment` the `Attachment` reads from the streams current bookmarked position so it misses 37 & 80 & the file is corrupt.  Try `uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream.Position = 0;` as the last line of `IsAcctngFileHeaderValid` to reset it.

Comment: Okay, Got it! Your suggestion works. Thank you very much!! If you post it as an answer, I'll mark it as a solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the stream to the `Attachment` constructor it's offset by 2 bytes because you read from it earlier in `IsAcctngFileHeaderValid` corrupting the data.

Reset the stream position using `uplAcctngAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream.Position = 0;`  when `IsAcctngFileHeaderValid` is done reading.